# What does R5m mean in an APRS entry for a WinLink gateway?

Tags: aprs, winlink

If you look at an [APRS description for a WinLink gateway](https://aprs.fi/info/a/KE7ARH-10#:%7E:text=144.950MHz%201200%20R5m%20Winlink%20Gateway), you'll see something like "144.950MHz 1200 R5m Winlink Gateway". I know that means it's a 1200 baud packet station serving as a Winlink Gateway, but **what does the *R5m* mean**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimated range (5 miles). I think 5 miles is the default, so it might not be indicative, but it probably indicates that it's a smaller station in someone's backyard.